# Не работает ЧПУ на Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, seo

Привет всем! 
В своём проекте на Yii2 реализовал user-friendly (ЧПУ) ссылки, как описано в статье [тут](http://bar-data.com/blog/yii2/beautiful-url-link-to-yii2-or-do-controlled-sef-links). В БД записываю alias: 'test-alias.html', а в route пишу 'site/about' и всё работает на Ура. Но если записать в БД route типа 'category/2', ЧПУ ссылка не формируется (просто идёт на mysite.com/ru/category/2).
У меня ссылка формируется вот так:

```
Url::to(['category/view', 'id' => $hit->id])
```

и в UrlManager стоит правило:

```
'category/<id:\d+>' => 'category/view',
```

**Как сделать так чтобы при переходе по ссылке типа "category/2" формировалась и открывалась ЧПУ ссылка?**

Comment: Покажите все правила. И как понять фразу "формировалась и открывалась ЧПУ ссылка?"

Comment: Вот все правила http://prntscr.com/dcnido

Answer (score 1):

Нужно создавать ссылку через `Url::toRoute()`

```
Url::toRoute(['category/view', 'id' => $hit->id])
```

`Url::toRoute()` берет ссылку из карты маршрутов в то время как `Url::to()` берет строку как ссылку

Answer (score 0):

Rule `'category/<id:\d+>' => 'category/view'`, говорит что для урла site.com/category/7 нужно вызывать действие view контроллера category и передавать ему параметр id целого типа. справедливо и обратное: если указать маршрут category/view и указать параметр id то Url::to() сгенерирует урл типа category/id.

а вы пытаетесь сформировать урл задавая неправильный роут. роут не может быть category/2. в роуте должно быть действие (с контроллером, параметрами и модулем если надо)

попробуйте еще раз осмыслить https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/runtime-routing.md и понять все)

к предыдущему ответу: Url::to() тоже строит урл по маршруту (если передали массив) или просто выводит строку